# Lost primary DC, and second one was never promted

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I lost my primary DC, and as it turns out, the second one was never really promoted.  I wanted to know what is the best possible way (if any) to recover usernames and servers after building a new DC.  Is it just simply impossible?  Should I just build my new DC with a new name, and rejoin the computers to that new DC?

Please offer up some advice.  Fortunately, there is about 5 users, and 10 servers running on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a System State backup of the original DC then recovery isn't possible. You'll have to start from scratch and build a new domain.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Do I need to build the new domain, and rejoin the existing computers to it, or should I really wipe everything clean?

Comment: You don't need to wipe the workstations but you will need to create user accounts in the new domain for all of your users and you'll need to join all of the workstations to the new domain. This means that all of your users will have new user profiles on their workstations and will need to setup their applications anew (Outlook, etc.) and will need any data copied from their old user profile to their new user profile.

Comment: I have no affiliation with the company, but there is a handy utility called User Migration Wizard that I've used a lot.  It doesn't actually "migrate," it adjusts permissions, etc. on an existing profile to allow it to be used w/ a different login.